Proxy outbound diameter traffic with haproxy
I would like to have a egress-static-ip server on which I installed haproxy with this configuration:
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000



frontend diameterX
  mode tcp
  bind *:3869
  default_backend diameter

backend diameter
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  option log-health-checks
  balance leastconn
  timeout server 1200000
  timeout connect 3000
  stick-table type ip  size 1m  expire 30m

  #stick match src
  #stick store-request src
  stick on src
  server s1 XXXX:3869

Unfortunately is not working for diameter tcp. App is sending request to server, but got -1 packet instead. It is possible to set a egress-proxy for diameter over tcp?
